# Styling the second of two consecutive <dd>s in a definition list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select the second `<dd>` when there are two in a row?  For example, I want to be able to select the `<dd>`s containing the word 'film' below for styling.

```
<dl>
  <dt>September 30</dt>
  <dd>Event 1</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>October 3</dt>
  <dd>Event 2</dd>

  <dt>October 21</dt>
  <dd>Event 3</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>October 28</dt>
  <dd>Event 4</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>Novermber 11</dt>
  <dd>Event 5</dd>
</dl>
```

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
dl dt + dd + dd {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tukngxo5/

[image]

Comment: The `dl` selector is probably unnecessary. You can probably get away with the assumption that `dt` and `dd` will always be descendants of `dl`. You could not make this same assumption for `li` elements w.r.t. `menu`/`ol`/`ul`, but you can for `dt`/`dd`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
dd + dd {
}
```

It will always select a `dd` that is directly followed by another `dd`

```css
dd + dd {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>September 30</dt>
  <dd>Event 1</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>October 3</dt>
  <dd>Event 2</dd>

  <dt>October 21</dt>
  <dd>Event 3</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>October 28</dt>
  <dd>Event 4</dd>
  <dd>film</dd>

  <dt>Novermber 11</dt>
  <dd>Event 5</dd>
</dl>
```